# Velocity Templates Path Outside JBoss

Tags: templates, jboss, velocity

I have an ear file deployed inside JBoss AS 7.1 and I am having some troubles setting a velocity templates directory.
The ideal would be manipulating these files in a directory outside JBoss, configured in my .properties file, instead of using a classpath resource loader.

Is there any good way to use a file resource loader for instance, to manipulate my templates outside the jboss context?

Thanks,

--Roederick

Answer (score 1):

Sure; set the `resource.loader` and `file.resource.loader.class` properties:

```
resource.loader = file
file.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
```

Then set the appropriate properties for the `FileResourceLoader`:

```
file.resource.loader.path = /opt/templates
file.resource.loader.cache = true
file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval = 2
```

Taken from the [Configuring Resource Loaders section](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/developer-guide.html#configuring_resource_loaders) of the [Velocity Dev Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/developer-guide.html).

Comment: Tried to do something like that yesterday for a while without success, I was getting the error:

Unable to find resource "<path>/<template>" in any Resource Loader

But I'll give it another shot today with cool head. Thanks.

Comment: @Roederick Without any context, I don't have any idea what that msg would mean; I don't even know how you're trying to use Velocity.